# Is there any SonarQube static code analysis for scanning Rust or Elixir code repositories?

Tags: rust, sonarqube, elixir, gitlab-ci, rust-clippy

I have a Gitlab Pipeline for SonarQube which can scan technologies like Node.js, Java, and PHP, but not with Rust and Elixir.

I tried the links below for Rust, but it seems like Rust lacks support.

https://gist.github.com/kaypee90/48f4a5b16c79ab1a0e3a256c7d3937a7
https://github.com/elegoff/sonar-rust

[image: Error]

Asking here maybe someone has faced a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: Frame challenge: what sort of functionality would you want SonarQube to perform on top of what the Rust compiler itself plus `cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` give you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SonarQube does not provide any analysis for Rust at this time: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/overview/

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [sonar-rust](https://github.com/elegoff/sonar-rust) seems to add Rust support to SonarQube.

Quote from Readme:

> The plugin enables analysis of Rust language within SonarQube, which is an open platform to manage code quality. It is compatible with SonarQube 8.9 and above (Latest tested SonarQube version is v9.8)

According to the [FAQ](https://github.com/elegoff/sonar-rust/blob/master/FAQ.md#can-i-scan-my-rust-source-code-from-a-cicd-pipeline--can-i-get-pull-requests-decoration-) the plugin should be usable in any CI-pipeline.

Have not tried it myself though.